# Deploy .war to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to deploy war from Jenkins to Cloud.

Could you please let me know how to deploy war file from Jenkins on my local to AWS Bean Stalk ?

I tried using a Jenkins post-process plugin to copy the artifact to S3, but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Failed to upload files java.io.IOException: put Destination [bucketName=https:, objectName=/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/test.war]:
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to s3.amazonaws.com/s3.amazonaws.com/ timed out at hudson.plugins.s3.S3Profile.upload(S3Profile.java:85) at hudson.plugins.s3.S3BucketPublisher.perform(S3BucketPublisher.java:143)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some work has been done on this.

http://purelyinstinctual.com/2013/03/18/automated-deployment-to-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-using-jenkins-on-ec2-part-2-guide/

Basically, this is just adding a post-build task to run the standard command line deployment scripts.

From the referenced page, assuming you have the post-build task plugin on Jenkins and the AWS command line tools installed:

**STEP 1**

In a Jenkins job configuration screen, add a “Post-build action” and choose the plugin “Publish artifacts to S3 bucket”, specify the Source (in our case, we use Maven so the source is target/.war and destination is your S3 bucket name)

**STEP 2**

Then, add a “Post-build task” (if you don’t have it, this is a plugin in Maven repo) to the same section above (“Post-build Actions”) and drag it below the “Publish artifacts to S3 bucket”. This is important that we want to make sure the war file is uploaded to S3 before proceeding with the scripts.

In the Post-build task portion, make sure you check the box “Run script only if all previous steps were successful”

In the script text area, put in the path of the script to automate the deployment (described in step 3 below). For us, we put something like this:

```
<path_to_script_file>/deploy.sh "$VERSION_NUMBER" "$VERSION_DESCRIPTION"
```

The $VERSION_NUMBER and $VERSION_DESCRIPTION are Jenkins’ build parameters and must be specified when a deployment is triggered. Both variables will be used for AEB deployment

**STEP 3**

The script

```
#!/bin/sh
export AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE=<path_to_your aws.key file>
export PATH=$PATH:<path to bin file inside the "api" folder inside the AEB Command line tool (A)>
export PATH=$PATH:<path to root folder of s3cmd (B)>

//get the current time and append to the name of .war file that's being deployed.
//This will create a unique identifier for each .war file and allow us to rollback easily.
current_time=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
original_file="app.war"
new_file="app_$current_time.war"

//Rename the deployed war file with the new name.
s3cmd mv "s3://<your S3 bucket>/$original_file" "s3://<your S3 bucket>/$new_file"

//Create application version in AEB and link it with the renamed WAR file
elastic-beanstalk-create-application-version -a "Hoiio App" -l "$1" -d "$2" -s "<your S3 bucket>/$new_file"
```

Comment: I tried this but it seems like this tutorial is for Jenkins running on the EC2 but in my case i have Jenkins running on my local machine.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. You should still be able to copy the war file to your s3 bucket and relaunch the EBC instance with the new war parameter.  I have done this using the beanstalker maven plugin, which is similar in nature.

Comment: If you tried this, please add any error messages or results to your question, so we can help resolve the issues, rather than provide links to pages you've already looked at.

Comment: ERROR: Failed to upload files
java.io.IOException: put Destination [bucketName=https:, objectName=/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/test.war]: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to s3.amazonaws.com/s3.amazonaws.com/ timed out
 at hudson.plugins.s3.S3Profile.upload(S3Profile.java:85)
 at hudson.plugins.s3.S3BucketPublisher.perform(S3BucketPublisher.java:143)